Why do speaker buttons work on desktop and Android but not on iOS in React?
I have speaker buttons that work fine on desktop and Android but not on iOS. Code attached below.
This is the button:
<button className='cursor-pointer' onClick={() => handlePlayAudio('question')}>
    <AiFillSound className="text-4xl mb-4"/>
</button>

And this is the audio handler:
const handlePlayAudio = (audioType) => {
    const audioData = audioType === 'question' ? questionData : answerData;
    if (audioData) {
      const audioBlob = new Blob([audioData]);
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      audio.play();
    }
  };

I have tried using the CSS class 'cursor-pointer' from TailwindCSS. This does not work. I have tried using an onPointerEnter, as this was the most recent suggestion I could find for this issue, but that also did not solve the issue.

Welcome to SO! Please can you clarify what does not work? You show code for audio feature, but then refer to CSS. What is the specific expected behavior?

Yeah, sure, so when you click on that button it should fire the handlePlayAudio handler shown. It does os on desktop and on Android phones, but if you tap on the button on iOS, it does not function, there is no audio played.

It does not work on Safari either.
